# Massive performance slowdown in C# SOAP client when one AppDomain per thread versus just one (ie the primary) AppDomain

Tags: c#, multithreading, web-services, soap, mono

A piece of code I inherited recently uses separate AppDomains to parallelise calls to a SOAP web service.

We were seeing an intermittent bug in Mono which caused crashes when the AppDomains were unloaded, and since AppDomains seemed like overkill for the purposes of multithreading calls to the service, I removed them and simplified the code. All seemed to work fine, however, there was a drastic performance regression (around 3x slower).

I put together a simplified chunk of code to reproduce the issue:

```
var sw = new Stopwatch();
sw.Start();

var tasks = new List<Task>();
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i ++) {
    tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
        var domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("MyAppDomain");
        var processor = (MarshalledProcessor)domain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(
            typeof(MarshalledProcessor).Assembly.FullName,
            typeof(MarshalledProcessor).FullName);

        // comment out the line below to use the AppDomain version.
        processor = new MarshalledProcessor();
        for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++)  {
            processor.SendRequest();
        }
    }));
}

Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
_log.Info(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

[Serializable]
public class MarshalledProcessor : MarshalByRefObject {
    public MarshalledProcessor() {
        proxy = new Proxy {
            Url = Configuration.Instance.ServiceUrl,
            SecurityTokenValue = new SecurityToken {
                Username = String.Empty,
                Password = String.Empty,
                ServiceVersion = "1",
                ServiceName = "SomeWebServiceFunction"
            }
        };
    }

    readonly Proxy proxy;

    public void SendRequest() {
        proxy.RDService("<xml>some valid xml for the web service request</xml>");
    }
}
```

Note that the `Proxy` class here is auto-generated from the WSDL using the mono Web Services Description Language Utility, and inherits from `System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol`.

When I run the above code (with actual values for the web request of course), against the production web service, I get completely performance, depending on whether I use separate AppDomain or not.

- With AppDomain: 56612 ms
- Without separate AppDomains: 138250 ms

As another data point, if I only run a single thread (ie remove the first loop, thus doing 1/5th the work), the timings are:

- With AppDomain: 51104 ms
- Without separate AppDomains: 50902 ms

Why would it be so much faster (in the parallel case) using the AppDomain? Is there some static lock buried in the `SoapHttpClientProtocol` object?

Here is are the longest running methods, from profiling the above test code:

**Without the AppDomain**

```
Method call summary
Total(ms) Self(ms)      Calls Method name
 4364088        4       1012 System.Threading.ExecutionContext:Run (System.Threading.ExecutionContext,System.Threading.ContextCallback,object,bool)
 4364084        8       1012 System.Threading.ExecutionContext:RunInternal (System.Threading.ExecutionContext,System.Threading.ContextCallback,object,bool)
 4319266       12       7580 System.Threading.WaitHandle:WaitOne (int,bool)
 4319260  4319260       7579 (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Threading.WaitHandle:WaitOne_internal (System.Threading.WaitHandle,intptr,int,bool)
 2475342       29      29641 (wrapper runtime-invoke) <Module>:runtime_invoke_bool (object,intptr,intptr,intptr)
 2475288       25      29630 System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback:PerformWaitCallback ()
 2475262       91      29630 System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue:Dispatch ()
 2463724        1         10 System.Threading.Tasks.Task:System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem ()
 2463722        8         10 System.Threading.Tasks.Task:ExecuteEntry (bool)
 2463713        2         10 System.Threading.Tasks.Task:ExecuteWithThreadLocal (System.Threading.Tasks.Task&)
 2463708        1         10 System.Threading.Tasks.Task:ExecutionContextCallback (object)
 2463706        1         10 System.Threading.Tasks.Task:Execute ()
 2463705        5         10 System.Threading.Tasks.Task:InnerInvoke ()
 2463700       14         10 COG.PonteDeiSospiri.PdSDaemon.CuratorDaemon:<Run>m__0 ()
 2434613        7       1000 COG.PonteDeiSospiri.PdSDaemon.CuratorDaemon/MarshalledProcessor:SendRequest ()
 2433126        2       1000 (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) RdwsProxy:RDService (string)
 2433123       11       1000 RdwsProxy:RDService (string)
 2433111       42       1000 System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol:Invoke (string,object[])
 1952284       13       1000 System.Net.HttpWebRequest:GetRequestStream ()
 1916760        4       4434 (wrapper runtime-invoke) object:runtime_invoke_void__this__ (object,intptr,intptr,intptr)
 1900230        2         10 System.Threading.ThreadHelper:ThreadStart ()
 1900227        0         10 System.Threading.ExecutionContext:Run (System.Threading.ExecutionContext,System.Threading.ContextCallback,object)
 1900218       18         10 System.Threading.ThreadHelper:ThreadStart_Context (object)
 1900199       50         10 System.Threading.Timer/Scheduler:SchedulerThread ()
 1900094        4       4846 System.Threading.WaitHandle:WaitOne (int)
```

**With the AppDomain**

```
Method call summary
Total(ms) Self(ms)      Calls Method name
 1467552        4       2000 (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) RdwsProxy:RDService (string)
  820526        0       1007 System.Threading.ExecutionContext:Run (System.Threading.ExecutionContext,System.Threading.ContextCallback,object,bool)
  820525       11       1007 System.Threading.ExecutionContext:RunInternal (System.Threading.ExecutionContext,System.Threading.ContextCallback,object,bool)
  778335   778335       3246 (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Threading.WaitHandle:WaitOne_internal (System.Threading.WaitHandle,intptr,int,bool)
  778334        5       3245 System.Threading.WaitHandle:WaitOne (int,bool)
  771719       32      29659 (wrapper runtime-invoke) <Module>:runtime_invoke_bool (object,intptr,intptr,intptr)
  771662       27      29648 System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback:PerformWaitCallback ()
  771635       87      29648 System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue:Dispatch ()
  760104        3         10 System.Threading.Tasks.Task:System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem ()
  760100        5         10 System.Threading.Tasks.Task:ExecuteEntry (bool)
  760095        1         10 System.Threading.Tasks.Task:ExecuteWithThreadLocal (System.Threading.Tasks.Task&)
  760091        1         10 System.Threading.Tasks.Task:ExecutionContextCallback (object)
  760089        0         10 System.Threading.Tasks.Task:Execute ()
  760089        6         10 System.Threading.Tasks.Task:InnerInvoke ()
  760082        1         10 COG.PonteDeiSospiri.PdSDaemon.CuratorDaemon:<Run>m__0 ()
  736082        5       1000 COG.PonteDeiSospiri.PdSDaemon.CuratorDaemon/MarshalledProcessor:SendRequest ()
  734709        4       1000 (wrapper xdomain-invoke) RdwsProxy:RDService (string)
  733723        5       1000 (wrapper xdomain-dispatch) RdwsProxy:RDService (object,byte[]&,byte[]&,string)
  732839       16       1000 RdwsProxy:RDService (string)
  732821       65       1000 System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol:Invoke (string,object[])
  655908        4       1000 System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpWebClientProtocol:GetWebResponse (System.Net.WebRequest)
  655904        2       1000 System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebClientProtocol:GetWebResponse (System.Net.WebRequest)
  655900       11       1000 System.Net.HttpWebRequest:GetResponse ()
  652235        2       1682 System.Net.SimpleAsyncResult:WaitUntilComplete (int,bool)
  651904        2       1000 System.Net.HttpWebRequest:EndGetResponse (System.IAsyncResult)
```

One interesting difference is:

No AppDomains:

```
4319260  4319260       7579 (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Threading.WaitHandle:WaitOne_internal (System.Threading.WaitHandle,intptr,int,bool)
```

Multiple AppDomains:

```
778335   778335       3246 (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Threading.WaitHandle:WaitOne_internal (System.Threading.WaitHandle,intptr,int,bool)
```

If I'm reading this correctly, we spend over 5 times as long waiting on locks, and over twice as many waits in total.

This supports my theory that there is some global locking going on in the mono soap client, which is circumvented when using multiple app domains.

Tracing the calls to this lock shows the following discrepancy (omitting all the traces which have roughly the same number of calls).

```
251 calls from:
    System.Threading.ExecutionContext:Run (System.Threading.ExecutionContext,System.Threading.ContextCallback,object,bool)
    System.Threading.ExecutionContext:RunInternal (System.Threading.ExecutionContext,System.Threading.ContextCallback,object,bool)
    System.Threading.ThreadHelper:ThreadStart_Context (object)
    System.Threading.Timer/Scheduler:SchedulerThread ()
    System.Threading.WaitHandle:WaitOne (int)
    System.Threading.WaitHandle:WaitOne (int,bool)


4581 calls from:
    System.Threading.ExecutionContext:Run (System.Threading.ExecutionContext,System.Threading.ContextCallback,object,bool)
    System.Threading.ExecutionContext:RunInternal (System.Threading.ExecutionContext,System.Threading.ContextCallback,object,bool)
    System.Threading.ThreadHelper:ThreadStart_Context (object)
    System.Threading.Timer/Scheduler:SchedulerThread ()
    System.Threading.WaitHandle:WaitOne (int)
    System.Threading.WaitHandle:WaitOne (int,bool)
```

Comment: Have you profiled the code to see where all the time is spent?

Comment: Good idea. Done, and added a summary of the profiling results.

Comment: Add the code without the appdomain so we can see how you call the soap service.

Comment: I can see at least a big fault in this code, there is always just one thread. Factory.StartNew(Action) will not create a new thread, will run the task on the thread it created the task. If you really want multiple threads use Task.Run or the StartNew overload which allows to specify a tastk scheduler and pass the default scheduler or use plain threads. Maybe the slowdown you see is the combination of the async tasks in one thread plus the use of a marshalbyref object without another app domain.

Comment: Thanks for the comments Gusman. The code as written above runs all threads in the primary AppDomain. In order to use one AppDomain per thread, you just comment out line 13 (with the comment above it). I'm confident that Task.Factory.StartNew indeed runs the provided Action in one of the worker threads from the threadpool. More detail here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321439(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @gusman The fact that StartNew uses the current scheduler instead of default really only comes into play if we have a special context (wpf being the prime example) and having startnew and continue with nested. Since this is not the case here we will end up with concurrency. Still best practice is finely to user Task.Run if 4.5 is available or otherwise specify the right parameters.

Comment: what version of mono is this?

Comment: @knocte We see the same performance issues in 4.2.1 and 4.0.5.